# Plotting a graph with logarithic axis - 3 y-values for every x-value

Tags: matlab, graph

I am trying to plot a graph of value value of a variable x on the x-axis; however, there are three values for each point, that is to say, natural frequency 1, natural frequency 2 and natural frequency 3. 
This is the code and it is not working:

```
M = [3 0 0; 0 2 0; 0 0 0.5]
% disp('Mass matrix [M]');
% disp(M);

for i=1:1000:60e06
    K = [i+7e06 i -6e06; i i+3e06 -3e06; -6e06 -3e06 10e06];
    % disp(K)
    [V,L]=eig(K,M);     % eig is a standard Matlab function
    values=diag(L);     % diag gets the values from the leading diagonal
    [values,I]=sort(values);    % sort into ascending order of frequency
    V(:,I)=V;                   % now sort the mode shape vectors
    freq=sqrt(values)/(2*pi);   % this divides all elements by 2 pi

    % disp('Eigenvalues [s^(-2)]');
    % disp(values');        % the quote mark after values prints the column vector as a row

    % disp('Frequencies [Hz]');
    % disp(freq');

    % disp('Mode shape vectors in the columns of matrix [V]');
    % disp(V);
      loglog(i, freq(1:1), i, freq(2:1), i, freq(3:1)
end
```

Apologies for the mistakes, I am a beginner.

Comment: `1:1`, `2:1` and `3:1` cannot be what you really mean—perhaps you intend `freq(1, 1)`, `freq(2, 1)` and `freq(3, 1)` but it's hard to tell: you have to be more specific than "not working". What did you see, vs. what did you expect to see? Also, note that without either a `hold on` or a `pause` after the `loglog`, the loop will just keep overwriting the plot faster than you can see.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing bracket in the end of your line

```
loglog(i, freq(1:1), i, freq(2:1), i, freq(3:1)
```

Also, I don't see the reason for your `2:1`, `3:1`, ...?!

Replace it by

```
loglog(i, freq(1), i, freq(2), i, freq(3))
```

and I don't see anything wrong with your plotting.

In general I would suggest to store the values of *freq* in some array and plot it separately. This will speed the script up a lot, i.e.

```
%preallocate freq, the number of iterations in the loop is important here
freq = zeros(3,length(1:1e3:60e6))

for i = ...
    %your loop goes here
    %remove freq = ...
    %remove loglog( ...
   freq(:,i) = sqrt(values)/(2*pi);   % this divides all elements by 2 pi
end

loglog(1:1e3:60e6, freq(1,:)) %plot first curve
loglog(1:1e3:60e6, freq(2,:)) %plot second curve
loglog(1:1e3:60e6, freq(3,:)) %plot third curve
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have the `loglog` inside the loop.

Before the loop, I put:

```
i_vals = 1:1000:60e06;
freq = zeros(3, length(i_vals));
```

I change the top of the loop to:

```
for n=1:length(i_vals)
    i = i_vals(n);
    K = [i+7e06 i -6e06; i i+3e06 -3e06; -6e06 -3e06 10e06];
    ...
```

Also change your `freq` assignment:

```
freq(:, n)=sqrt(values)/(2*pi);
```

Delete your `loglog` and put this after/outside your loop.

```
loglog(i_vals, freq')
```

Doing all of that gives me this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to use your method to plot three graphs: 1 for each frequency with 3 corresponding mode shapes (1 frequency corresponds to 3 mode shapes arranged in the column below in matrix V). However, none of the methods I used works.

Comment: Hey, your answer was really helpful last time, is there any possibility of answering my last question? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want three graphs, then make three graphs. `figure, loglog(i_vals, freq(1,:)), figure, loglog(i_vals, freq(2,:)), figure, loglog(i_vals, freq(3,:))`